# Catching Multiple Exceptions-C#

Tags: c#, exception

How can I catch multiple Exceptions in my code? Like I have the following code for `Delete` operation, I want to catch Exception for `REFERENCE constraint` and for `SqlConnection` Exception.

```
public void DeleteProduct(Product p)
{
    try
    {
        using (IDbCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = SpDeleteProduct;
            dbConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
        throw new FaultException(new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText(ex.Message)));
    }  
}
```

Then in my client code I want to check the type of Exception thrown so I can show a personalized message to the user:

```
void DeleteProductCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        FaultException fault = e.Error as FaultException;
        //Something like
        // if e.Error == SqlConnection Exception
        GetExceptionMessage("Error occured in connecting to DB");
        // if e.Error == Refeence constraint Exception
        GetExceptionMessage("foreign key violation");
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can catch specific exception in separate catch blocks

```
try
{
    using (IDbCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = SpDeleteProduct;
        dbConnection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   //Your exception specific code...
}  
catch (Exception ex) 
{
   //Your exception specific code...
}
```

As for good coding practice don't catch generic exception -`catch (Exception ex)` instead you catch only specific exception which you are expecting and dont catch generic exception. Even if you catch them throw them.

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  // do your logging only if required
   throw; //throw it back
}
```

Comment: Is it valid? `catch (SqlConnection ex)` . I get error `SqlConnection doesn't exist`

Comment: I think he probably meant SqlException